# MongoDB Covered Query For Two Fields Without Compound Index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can you perform a MongoDB covered query for two fields, for example

```
db.collection.find( { _id: 1, a: 2 } )
```

**without** having a compound index such as

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { _id: 1, a: 1 } )
```

but instead having only one index for _id (you get that by default) and another index for field "a", as in

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { a: 1 } )
```

In other words, I'd like to know if in order to perform a covered query for two fields I need a compound index vs. needing only two single (i.e., not compound) indexes, one for each field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries only use one [index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/).

Your example shows `_id` as one of the elements of your index? `_id` Needs to be unique in a collection, so it wouldn't make sense to make a compound index of `_id` and something else.

If you instead had:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { a: 1, b: 1 })
```

You could then use the `a` index as needed, independently, or as a compound index with `b`.

Comment: That helps, thanks. Comment: "Queries only use one index." Where does it say this?

Comment: @GSchv http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#create-indexes-to-support-your-queries check the last line of that section: "With the exception of queries that use the $or operator, a query cannot use multiple indexes. A query must use only one index." there are other places but that was the first place I looked