# What Happens When Querying For Two Indexed (not compound) Fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What happens when you query two fields, given that they're not part of a compound index, for example:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { a: 1 } )
db.collection.ensureIndex( { b: 1 } )

db.collection.find( { a: 2, b: 2 } )
```

I'd like to know if a number of documents might be scanned, or if Mongo DB won't scan anything and the `explain()` will return:

```
indexOnly: YES
```

Comment: Not sure why you're asking the same question in multiple ways? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296854/mongodb-covered-query-for-two-fields-without-compound-index The [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/) cover this information very well.

Comment: Those are two different questions. The other one had to do with the "_id" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explain only returns `indexOnly` if all the values you are looking for are in index (including the sort). Basically it denotes a covered index: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries

In this case you are querying by two fields but only one of them is in one individual index.

Considering MongoDB cannot use multiple indexes for a single clause (`$or` being the exception since it is multi-clause here also it is different than a normal query) it will not do an `indexOnly` query, instead it will search the collection by the index on `a` and then do a full document scan of the documents that contain `b` within that range to understand its values and return a result.

Do also note that to use `indexOnly` cursors properly you should make the following parts of the your query fit into a single index:

- Condition
- Projection
- Sort

i.e.:

```
db.ensureIndex({a:1,b:1});
db.col.find({a:1}, {_id:0,a:1,b:1}).sort({b:1});
```

Would use a `indexOnly` cursor.

Comment: Thanks. So it'd pretty much ignore the "b" individual index? And in your example, the {_id:0...} part of the projection is a must? In your example, is the sort({b:1}) a must as well?

Comment: @GSchv The sort isn't required, I just placed in as an example. The `_id` part is though, from the link I pasted above: "...must explicitly exclude the _id field from the result set, unless the index includes _id."

Comment: Thanks, answer incredibly helpful.

Comment: @GSchv Glad to have helped :)